# .Net Core API container on Minikube not running

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, minikube, wsl-2

I have a deployment on Minikube for a .Net Core 5 API that is not returning response when I try to invoke it from Postman. When I run a GET from Postman to the exposed port (32580) and endpoint `http:// localhost:32580/api/platforms/` I get:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Oddly enough I was previously getting a `Connection refused` (before I restarted my Docker desktop). The container works perfectly when I use Docker but once I deployed it to Kubernetes context it no longer works.

I am unsure how exactly I can debug the container and get more meaningful error detail.

I have tried the following:

1. Checking status of Deployment (platforms-depl)

---

```
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE 
hello-minikube   1/1     1            1           134d
ping-google      0/1     1            0           2d2h
platforms-depl   1/1     1            1           115m
```

2. Checking status of Pod (platforms-depl-84d7f5bdc6-sgxcp)

---

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE 
hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-6mfmf   1/1     Running            21         134d
ping-google-5f84d66fcc-kbb7j      0/1     ImagePullBackOff   151        2d2h
platforms-depl-84d7f5bdc6-sgxcp   1/1     Running            1          115m
```

3. Running `kubectl describe pod platforms-depl-84d7f5bdc6-sgxcp` gives below output (truncated):

---

```
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.3
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/platforms-depl-84d7f5bdc6
Containers:
  platformservice:
    Container ID:   docker://a73ce2dc737206e502df94066247299a6dcb6a038087d0f42ffc6e3b9dd194dd
    Image:          golide/platformservice:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://golide/platformservice@sha256:bbed5f1d7238d2c466a6782333f8512d2e464f94aa64d8670214646a81b616c7      
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 28 Sep 2021 15:12:22 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-rl5kf (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
```

4. When I run `docker ps` I cannot see the container and it also doesn't appear in the list of running containers in VS Code Docker/Containers extension.
5. `kubectl get services` gives me the following:

---

```
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE 
hello-minikube          NodePort    10.99.23.44    <none>        8080:31378/TCP   134d
kubernetes              ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          134d
paymentsapi             NodePort    10.111.243.3   <none>        5000:30385/TCP   108d
platformnpservice-srv   NodePort    10.98.131.95   <none>        80:32580/TCP     2d2h
```

Then tried pinging the ClusterIP:

```
Pinging 10.98.131.95 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
 
Ping statistics for 10.98.131.95:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

What am I missing?

I read in suggestions I have to exec into the pod so that I get meaningful output but I'm not sure of the exact commands to run. I tried:

```
kubectl exec POD -p platforms-depl-84d7f5bdc6-sgxcp
```

only to get error:

```
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
Error from server (NotFound): pods "POD" not found
```

My environment Docker Linux containers with WSL2 on Windows 10.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which pod contains your .net core app? Did you try getting the logs using `kubectl logs platforms-depl-84d7f5bdc6-sgxcp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing which is worth to note that generally minikube has a lot of possible [drivers to choose from](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) - in my case I found the `docker` drive to be most easiest to use.

My setup is:

- WSL2
- Docker Desktop with [Docker Desktop WLS 2 backend enabled](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/)

I used following command to start minikube: `minikube start --driver=docker`.
If you are using other driver I suggest moving to the `docker` one.

Answering your question:

*What am I missing ?*

By setting nodePort service type you are exposing your deployment / replica set using node IP address which not accessible from Windows host (when using `docker` driver). It's because all Kubernetes cluster resources are setup inside Docker container, which is isolated.

However, minikube offers simple solution to make available specified nodePort service to your Windows host. [Just run `minikube service` command which will create a tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/service/). Let's check it.

You setup `platformnpservice-srv` service so you need to use this name in `minikube service` command instead of `testmini` which I used:

```
minikube service --url testmini
  Starting tunnel for service testmini.
|-----------|----------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |   NAME   | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|----------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | testmini |             | http://127.0.0.1:33849 |
|-----------|----------|-------------|------------------------|
http://127.0.0.1:33849
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on linux, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

Note the last sentence - we need to keep this terminal window to be open, otherwise the tunnel won't be established.
Now, on my Windows host, in the browser I'm opening: `http://127.0.0.1:33849/api/platforms` website. The output is following:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Dot Net","publisher":"Microsoft","cost":"Free"},{"id":2,"name":"Linux","publisher":"Ubuntu","cost":"Free"},{"id":3,"name":"Kubernetes","publisher":"CNCF","cost":"Free"},{"id":4,"name":"SQL Express","publisher":"Microsoft","cost":"Free"}]
```

Voila! Seems that everything is working properly.

Also, other notes:

> tried pinging the ClusterIP

The ClusterIP is [internal address which is only accessible from the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types), so you can't ping it from Windows host neither WSL2.

> *kubectl exec POD -p platforms-depl-84d7f5bdc6-sgxcp*

As output suggests, you need to [specify command you want to exec on the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec). If you just want to get bash shell, use the following:

```
kubectl exec -it platforms-depl-84d7f5bdc6-sgxcp -- sh
```